# What is the easiest way to convert array with keys to other format

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => 10
    [key2] => 7
    [key3] => 8
)
```

I want to convert it to the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [section] => key1
            [quantity] => 10
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [section] => key2
            [quantity] => 7
        ),
    [2] => Array
        (
            [section] => key3
            [quantity] => 8
        )
)
```

I tried to use `array_map` function, but inside the closure I get only a value without a key. Please, suggest me the easiest way to do it, without `foreach`.

**Update**
I think using foreach requires creation of an additional variable which makes the code messy and resource requiring.

Comment: What's your reason for not using foreach?

Comment: Unless you have a really really good reason not to, foreach is the way to do this

Comment: @danjam want to make it easy to read and more flexible

Comment: You can do `array_map` in combination with `array_keys`. You could make an iterator. `foreach` is the simplest solution. If readability is a concern opt for the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `array_walk` as

```
$result = array();
array_walk($arr, function ($v,$k) use(&$result) {
     $result[] = array('section' => $k, 'quantity' => $v);
});
```

[**demo using array_walk**](https://eval.in/376104)

Using `foreach`

```
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $result[] = array('section' => $key, 'quantity' => $value);
}

print_r($result);
```

[**demo using foreach**](https://eval.in/376105)

Comment: best answer for me is first one. upvoted to you.thanks

Comment: Thanks.@anantkumarsingh. I have just showed the another way but going though foreach is better for novice too...

Comment: yes i agreed to you second is better for novice, but it's not hard to understand first one too.

Comment: Added my own solution, if you interested, you can take a look at it :) there is no usage of additional array and referencing variables ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason not to use foreach for this.  The best solution would be:

```
$cookedArray = [];
foreach ($rawArray as $key => $value)
{
    $cookedArray [] = ["section" => $key, "quantity" => $value];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$previous_array=array(
    'key1' => 10,
    'key2' => 7,
    'key3' => 8,
);

$new_array=array();
foreach($previous_array as $key => $value):
    $new_array[]=array('section'=>$key,'quantity'=>$value);

endforeach;
Print_r($new_array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [section] => key1
            [quantity] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [section] => key2
            [quantity] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [section] => key3
            [quantity] => 8
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

About by updated requirement, I myself have came to this solution:

```
$section = array_map(function ($key,$value) {
    return ['section' => $key, 'quantity' => $value];
}, array_keys($section), array_values($section));
```

The only concern is about keys and values. Now I am testing, won't it mess up with each other, I mean keys mix with values?

**Update**
It worked fine. Thanks to the pointing of @Halcyon in comments. And all others who suggested solutions.